# More logical expressions of "爸爸把你生下来"

Tags: word, word-requests, expressions, colloquialisms

I get stuck by the "生" in expressions like these two:

1. [闺女，爸爸把你生下来，却有很多的无奈](http://www.360doc.com/content/11/0528/08/1607624_120024284.shtml)
2. [世界上有爸爸生孩子的吗？还真有！](https://www.sohu.com/a/275603827_100133993)

More examples like the first one can be found [here](https://www.baidu.com/s?ie=utf-8&f=8&rsv_bp=1&rsv_idx=1&tn=baidu&wd=%E7%88%B8%E7%88%B8%E8%A6%81%E7%94%9F%E7%94%B7%E5%AD%A9&fenlei=256&oq=%25E7%2588%25B8%25E7%2588%25B8%25E7%2594%259F%25E4%25BD%25A0%25E4%25B8%258B%25E6%259D%25A5&rsv_pq=ce830fcf00002953&rsv_t=a8bb1pccz2Qqpt9H2VdXp8F3dPChwYZ3dtV5xg2i3RmTecnfl1QBZx14TzM&rqlang=cn&rsv_dl=tb&rsv_enter=1&rsv_btype=t&inputT=3050&rsv_sug3=38&rsv_sug1=28&rsv_sug7=100&rsv_sug2=0&rsv_sug4=4066):

1. [为何大多数爸爸想生儿子](https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1633671840074147036&wfr=spider&for=pc)
2. [准爸爸怎么样可以生男孩](https://jingyan.baidu.com/article/574c5219c662d16c8d9dc134.html)

Can a father 生 a child or not? Do the two "生"s in the above titles have the same [word sense](https://www.purpleculture.net/dictionary-details/?word=%E7%94%9F)? If the two differ, what if we change the first one to "闺女，妈妈把你生下来，却有很多的无奈"?

I am Chinese, but I feel very strange or a little embarrassed hearing the expression of "爸爸把你生下来". Are there some intuitive or unembarrassing expression alternatives to it?

Comment: "生" means "give birth" In both sentences, so "爸爸把你生下来" is considered an inappropriate expression. However, "爸妈把你生下来" or "父母把你生下来" would be fine.

Comment: @r13 Yes, but the inappropriate expression is very common, especially in colloquial Chinese.

Comment: They could be right after all, as there exists a third gender :)

Answer (score 4):

> 闺女，爸爸把你生下来，却有很多的无奈

> 世界上有爸爸生孩子的吗？还真有！

The first 生 means "give life", as in 父母生我養我 (my parents gave me life and nurtured me)

The second 生 means "give birth" (生育)

生 can also mean "create", as in 天生萬物 (Nature created everything)

The sentence "爸爸把你生下来" feels strange because 生 mostly means "give birth" in day-to-day conversation, you have to take a second to decide 生 here really means "give life"

You can change it to "爸媽我們生了你" (We, your parents gave you life)

Answer (score 0):

The answer Tang ho gave is very good, and I reccomend it to apply to real life.  However I don't think the titles in your question are within that answer.

In fiction, it is possible for a male to give birth like a woman, because fiction isn't real.  Its not a common trope but you see it in all sorts of genres of fiction, from horror to comedy to drama etc.

I believe your titles are using it to literally  refer to giving birth to a child as a male, they just aren't real occurances.  This is further confirmed by the images in the second link that are clearly refering to the concept of male pregnancy.